# How to resolve memory leak issue if object will be used in message handler?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

```
PostMessage(
    hwnd,
    MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_EVENT, 
    eEvent_NewMessage,
    (LPARAM)new NewMessageEvent(...)
);
```

Please observe `new NewMessageEvent`  in above line, I am creating new object of `NewMessageEvent` to send to message handler.

I made sure, I am calling `delete` for `NewMessageEvent` in message handler.

Problem is my static analysis tool is showing it as a memory leak. Now problem may be while using `PostMessage`, we are not sure it will be handled.

What should be my approach to fix this memory leak issue.

Comment: Static analysis tools have limits. Imagine this: `intptr_t x = (intptr_t)malloc(1); free((void*)x);` (particularly if you are moving `x` around), your tool will be unable to track that block of memory.

Comment: This is very brittle. If you are crossing a DLL boundary in between `PostMessage` and `delete`-ing the object in your message handler, things may break. COM is one way to safely transfer ownership. The easiest way (that will also make the code analysis tool happy) is to not transfer ownership at all. You can do this by using `SendMessage` instead, and `delete` the object when the call returns. If the callee does need a copy, have it construct a copy from the object you are passing.

Answer (score 2):

The recipient of the message has to delete the object. You also need to handle the scenario where the call to `PostMessage` fails. The code runs like this:

```
NewMessageEvent* event = new NewMessageEvent(...);
if (!PostMessage(hwnd, MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_EVENT, eEvent_NewMessage, (LPARAM)event))
{
    delete event;
    // handle the error condition
}
```

Then in the code that processes the message, the recipient, you do this:

```
case MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_EVENT:
    NewMessageEvent* event = (NewMessageEvent*)lParam;
    // handle the event
    delete event;
    break;
```

Assuming that you have done all of this, then you don't have a leak. It is impossible for a static analysis tool to work out where this object is destroyed. You will have to find a way to tell this tool to ignore that specific allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by placing a `MessageEvent *` object in a `std::set<MessageEvent *>` or `set<shared_ptr<MessageEvent>>` before calling PostMessage. When handling the message it has to be removed from the set.

The main advantage of this approach is that if the message is not handled (common event if it is posted while closing the window) then it is possible to destroy it anyway (actually no action is required if a smart pointer is used).

A drawback is that if the PostMessage is called from another thread then a mutex is required to handle this properly.